# MySQL query to order results by number of votes in another table for the specifc result/row

Tags: php, mysql, join, subquery

Okay, so  I have a query below I am trying to get to work.

Basically everything works up until the inner join of the 'votes' table. What I am trying to do is order the results of this query in accordance with the number of votes each content row has in another table called votes. I know I'm not too far off from what I need to do!

Thanks in advance!!

```
mysql_query("
SELECT content.id, content.type, content.title, content.url, users.username
FROM content 
INNER JOIN users ON content.uploaderuid = users.id 
INNER JOIN votes  ON votes.id = content.id
WHERE (content.type = 'pic') 
ORDER BY COUNT(votes.id) DESC");
```

Comment: Is the problem that the query doesn't get executed or that it produces the incorrect result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing:

```sql
SELECT content.id, content.type, content.title, content.url, users.username
FROM content 
INNER JOIN users ON content.uploaderuid = users.id 
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT id,COUNT(*) as voteCount
   FROM votes  
   GROUP BY id
) v ON v.id = content.id
WHERE (content.type = 'pic') 
ORDER BY v.voteCount DESC
```

When you do an INNER JOIN with votes table directly, if you have multiple occurrences of the same id, you will get a lot more rows than before you did the JOIN.

If you are only interested in the number of votes for each id, by doing a JOIN with a subquery that calculates the count of votes for each id, will leave your previous query results as they were, and lets you use the voteCount to order by it.

Comment: Thanks! This was the best solution for what I was trying to do! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the <kbd>[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7855d/3/0)</kbd> that demonstrates the below query:

```
SELECT c.id, c.type, c.title, c.url, u.username, COUNT(v.id)
FROM content AS c
INNER JOIN users AS u ON c.uploaderuid = u.id 
INNER JOIN votes AS v ON v.id = c.id
WHERE c.type = 'pic'
GROUP BY c.id, c.type, c.title, c.url, u.username
ORDER BY COUNT(v.id) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
SELECT c.id, c.type, c.title, c.url, u.username, COUNT(v.id) votes
FROM content c
INNER JOIN users u ON c.uploaderuid = u.id 
INNER JOIN votes v ON v.id = c.id
WHERE c.type = 'pic'
GROUP BY c.id, c.type, c.title, c.url, u.username
ORDER BY votes DESC
```